# Let's Start a Blog

Tags: discussion, blog

Over the last couple days, @SteveRobillard, @Ghanima, @Goldilocks, and myself have been discussing adding a blog to our community. With the Raspberry Pi Zero having been released, site graduation, and our community elections, we're seeing a lot of  growth and changes.

Adding a blog will allow us to create articles for commonly addressed questions that include how the user can start all the basic troubleshooting steps that always need to be addressed.  Using this, a user could be greeted and then asked to read a specific article rather than having a wall of unformatted text thrown at them.

We do **not** intend for this to replace our user interaction.  Rather, the post can explain the most common problems, and then ask the user to add specific information to their question. This is meant to facilitate better user interaction, not replace it.

Additionally, community members can post projects they're working on and get some feedback as their project grows. I feel that this will also help a lot of "Has anyone done x before?" and "Can I do y?" questions.

What other sites have blogs? [Several](http://stackexchange.com/blogs), of them! Their purposes and articles vary significantly based on the site and even the author.  Some are links to other site's tutorials, a full blown tutorial or article about a specific subject, a "look at my cool project" post, and others are simply announcements.

If we're going to create the blog, we need to decide a few things.

1. What will the blog be about?

   - I'd like to see: community announcements, people's projects, and tutorials for our more common questions.
2. Who, other than those that I have already listed would like to contribute?

   - Also, who specifically will be in charge of said blog?  We can be very open about contributing, but someone(s) will need to take the reins and make sure things are being posted and that it doesn't devolve into garbage.
3. How often should we be posting? Mondays? Days that end in "y"? Whenever someone feels like it?

Comment: In case you were thinking you'd use the Community Blog by SE, it's no longer available. But we've recommended other sites to use [Medium](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/2046/21321).  [Worldbuilding.SE](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/can-we-have-an-se-blog-for-this-site) is using it and is having success with it.

Comment: Here's another discussion that might be useful: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/403/do-we-want-a-community-blog-what-will-it-be-about-and-who-will-contribute?rq=1

Comment: I hosted a WordPress blog on a Raspberry Pi a while back. It would only be fitting if whoever hosted it, did it on an RPi.

Comment: @PatrickCook: I'm thinking WP might be too heavy for this many users on an RPi :-P. Lots of other potential CMS's though.

Comment: @PatrickCook - you would have to hope it won't become popular then :) Anyway blogs seem to come and go in the blink of a eye so reliable hosting would be a good idea.